# Coloring Julia Sets using Distance Estimation Relative to Zoom Depth

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, coloring, fractals

Using the distance estimation coloring algorithm learned from [here](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distancefractals/distancefractals.htm), I was able to color Julia Sets projected on a Riemann sphere, as with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcgnoPnG_jk) video. However, once I started displaying [polynomial matings of Julia Sets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ9k5khI39c), using this coloring algorithm provided inconsistent results, as shown in the first image below. Certain parts are clearer than others, and this is because the polynomial mating brings out deeper parts of the fractal *without zooming in*, and so using the same distance adjustment makes those zoomed in parts more "blurry" than the rest.

As such, what I think I need is some sort of algorithm to detect how "zoomed in" I am in the Julia set, so I can adjust the distance accordingly. I tried basing it off of how many iterations it takes for the orbit to escape (as the deeper you get, the more iterations it takes for the orbit to escape) but that didn't quite get the intended effect (second image below - certain parts are barely visible). Here is my code for the coloring:

```
for (iter = currentMatingIteration + 1; iter < maxIterations && (w.x * w.x + w.y * w.y < bailout*bailout); iter++)
{
    d2 *= 4.0 * w2;
    
    // Julia Set algorithm
    w = c_2(w) + c;

    w2 = w.x * w.x + w.y * w.y;

    // Distance checker
    if(w2 > maxDist)
        break;
}

float fineness = 7;     // the higher, the less "blurry"
//float fineness = 15;  // this is used for the second picture below

float d = sqrt(w2 / d2) * log(w2);  // this is the distance estimation
float dist = clamp(sqrt(d * pow(fineness, 2)), 0, 1);   // this is the adjustments I make for coloring

//float dist = clamp(sqrt(d * pow(fineness * (float(iter) / maxIterations), 2)), 0, 1);     // This is my attempt to solve this problem, used in the second picture below
```

My project is [here](https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating) for testing.

[image]
[image]

## Edit:

While this probably isn't a general solution to figuring out how deeply zoomed one is, what worked for this issue is calculating the derivative during the pull-back part of the mating algorithm, and using that as the initial value for calculating the distance estimation for each Julia Set (thanks to Claude in the comments). The successful result is below:

[image]
[image]

## Riemann Sphere Adjustment

Without adjustment:
[image]

With adjustment:
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating/blob/604fbcec275aec3b82f431e2b12e26e5f51dc7f1/OpenTK%20Reimann%20Mandlebrot/Shaders/shader.frag#L812 this todo item is probably relevant

Comment: @Claude I finally got around to completing that task item, however I don't think it has an effect on the coloring (unless I did something wrong)... I pushed those edits to the project anyways

Comment: https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating/blob/e2964d10cb03f4b7d566c717b2bf2ffa4df0bf0c/OpenTK%20Reimann%20Mandlebrot/Shaders/shader.frag#L798 here deriv needs to be somewhere on the RHS too

Comment: @Claude The solution was right in front of me the entire time! Thank you so much for pointing this out to me, I'm definitely on the right path now (even if I have no idea why it works). Now, I'm getting some sort of error with the following line, as the *p* hemisphere works perfectly but the upper *q* hemisphere isn't right (I tried copying the formula from your code, as my knowledge with the math is limited here): https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating/blob/5395beb94d89014e0db97694e8c41688ae2c49bc/OpenTK%20Reimann%20Mandlebrot/Shaders/shader.frag#L820

Comment: https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating/blob/5395beb94d89014e0db97694e8c41688ae2c49bc/OpenTK%20Reimann%20Mandlebrot/Shaders/shader.frag#L823 `dc_2(z * z)` looks suspicious

Comment: @Claude My lord, that was a major brain freeze there on my part... thanks you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The key point when generating distance estimated images is to base the derivatives relative to the correct scale.  For a typical 2D Julia set or Mandelbrot set image one takes derivatives relative to pixel spacing (really, including the transformation from pixel coordinates to complex plane into account when calculating derivatives with the chain rule).

Images need not have a simple linear mapping from pixels, for example your projections of the Riemann sphere in 3D.  Probably there is some need to take into account the stereographic projection, but perhaps the distortion is not too big for the region near 0.  Ideally derivatives (and thus distance estimates) would be scaled relative to surface distance on the sphere surface in 3D.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! I incorporated the adjustment to account for the Riemann sphere projection, and it seems to brighten more "darker" areas - although as you said, the distortion isn't that significant in either hemisphere as they both project on the Riemann sphere closer to 0 than infinity